# Why does my stack size differ depending on whether the build is Release or Debug?

Tags: c++

Environment: CodeBlocks on Windows 7 64 bit

```
void recurse(int i)
{
    int a = 9;
    cout<<i<<endl;
    recurse(++i);
}
int main()
{
recurse(1);
return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code in release mode, it easily exceeds 600k recursion calls, when in Debug mode it fails after 43385 calls.

Any idea why that is happening?

It is not because of the compiler optimizing away the `a=9` , without that statement I get 65078 calls in debug mode

Comment: 1) Check the linker settings for the default stack size.  2) Look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not sure how to check the linker settings (everything seems to be on default, couldnt see an option for stack size explicitly)   The generated assembly code is at http://www2.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/6WrB0T#view/tab-assembly/offset/00401802 and http://www2.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/KM1lcc#view/tab-assembly/offset/00401143 (the 2nd one is the release build), but its way beyond the sort of assembly I've interpreted earlier :(

Comment: The 2nd link may be incorrect, pls use http://www2.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/nxs5Ez instead

Comment: You also have to consider that release mode may have placed that integer parameter in a register and *not* on the stack.  Also, why is this important, as you really can't do anything aobut this and just accept that debug mode does not do optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

A debug build will perform stack overflow checks. To do that, it needs to alocate a bit of stack memory for each function call.

Besides, parameters will also be passed on the stack while a release build will probably use registers.